# Test for Randomness of a List

Tags: random

Giving a list of numbers, is it possible to test if that list is ***truly*** random? If it is, how does such a procedure work?

I'm not sure about the tag for this question, so I just used analysis.

Comment: Looking at the die hard tests will be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine if a generated list is truly random.  If the process that generates the list is random then any list would be equally probable and that would include lists that looked very unrandom.

However there are statistical tests that allow one to detect common forms of non randomness.  The "Diehard tests" are a collection of tests that help you find problems in your random number generation systems.